# How can i find match string in array without loop

Tags: javascript

How can i check array match string for example

```
var blocklist = ['jack','mark','jhon','fox'];

var str = "xxxxxxxxxxjackxxxxxxxxx";
```

How can i check for var `str` that not match array `blocklist`?

Comment: you mean , you want to know if string contains anything present in the array?

Comment: str not includes words in blocklist

Comment: Please check this once . blocklist.forEach(ele => {
            if(str.indexOf(ele)!==-1){
              console.log('yes');}
});  if the string contains anything in present in the array , it will console ' yes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find the string by using [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var blocklist = ['jack', 'mark', 'jhon', 'fox'],
    str = "xxxxxxxxxxjackxxxxxxxxx",
    result = blocklist.find(s => str.includes(s));

console.log(result);
```